# Can I use <script defer> safely now?

Tags: javascript, deferred-execution

From what I'm reading, the `defer` attribute on `<script>` is now [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/script-defer) but I never see it used or mentioned.

If you don't need to defer inline scripts and don't add scripts dynamically ([which cause problems in IE9- and Safari 4-](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/defer/)), it seems that **you could use it reliably and have [scripts run right before DOMContentLoaded](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#list-of-scripts-that-will-execute-when-the-document-has-finished-parsing) in the specified order** (which doesn't happen with `async`)

This is basically what most websites need: run a couple or more external scripts in sequence, on DOMready. For example:

```
<script defer src='jquery.js'></script>
<script defer src='jquery.some-plugin.js'></script>
<script defer src='my-scripts.js'></script>
```

Why isn't it widely used? Can I actually use it now?

Comment: Because most of us will include the script right before the `</body>` tag and avoid all these issues ?

Comment: That's what I'm arguing, **there are no issues** if you just replace "scripts before `</body>`" with "`defer` scripts in `<head>`". They even start downloading sooner, so there's an advantage in using `defer`

Comment: take a look for this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952009/defer-attribute-chrome

Comment: It isn't widely used for the same reason you mentioned in the first line: *is **now** widely supported*. Because, before now, it wasn't widely supported. Yes, it is a good idea to use `defer` for *deferred execution* as compared to *start downloading* just before the body ends!

Comment: I'm voting to re-open as this clearly can have an objective answer. caniuse.com's declarations can objectively be proved and disproved, and it's the same with answers here.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413279/defer-scripts-and-execution-order-on-browsers and FF bug related to implementation of defer: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212696

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit more research and I found that problems with `defer` don't stop at inline scripts and scripts added dynamically in IE9. There's **a long list of problems and inconsistencies** with various browsers on the HTML5 Boilerplate GitHub https://github.com/h5bp/lazyweb-requests/issues/42

It's such a shame, I feel that they should have tried improving on `defer` rather than working on the dubious `async` (dubious because it's only useful if the scripts don't depend on each other, which is rare for me)

Comment: At least there are JavaScript libraries out there that support asynchronous loading of scripts with dependencies (though if the scripts weren't written with one of those libraries in mind, it can take a bit of external setup/configuration to get things to work right).

Comment: `defer` never had a meaning for inline scripts (its presence is even forbidden on them), so that cannot be considered a "problem"

Answer (score -1):

You ask if:

> you could use `defer` reliably and have scripts run right before DOMContentLoaded **in the specified order**

Unfortunately, I don't see any specs or standards anywhere that say that `defer` scripts have to be executed in order, so I don't think you can rely on that in any browser. The specs merely say that `defer` scripts have to be executed after the DOM loads.