# HTML load one script after another script completes execution

Tags: javascript, html

In a HTML file, I have the following scripts:

```
<head>
  <script src="/script1.js" defer></script>
  <script src="/script2.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

In `script1`, I am loading another HTML file:

```
(async function() {
  await fetch("./header.html")
    .then(response => { return response.text() })
    .then(data => { document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = data; });
})()
```

The code in `script2` uses the elements from `header.html` which is being loaded by `script1`. With the current codes, `script2` doesn't wait for `header.html` to be completely fetched.

A proof of this is that I have added `console.log("1")` after the fetch of `script1`, and added `console.log("2")` at the beginning of `script2`. Even though in the HTML file, I am calling `script1` then `script2`, but `console.log('2')` appears before `console.log('1')`

Thus causing `script2` to read some null elements (which have not been rendered yet). I am trying to ensure that `script1` finishes executing (thus the fetch operation finishes) before running `script2`. How should I do this?

Comment: One simple way is to add the functionality from script2 into last the `then` of script1. Or at least call the script2 function in the promise of script1.

Comment: could you show the script2 code

Comment: How about https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadjs ? I think this does what you need, but it requires an additional library...

Comment: `script2` simply does `document.getElementById("some element in header.html").style.display = block`, but it generates an error of element undefined.

Comment: Multiple scripts with the `defer` attribute are added to a list of scripts to be executed once the document they are part of has completed loading. Whether they are executed in order is up to the parser. See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53274388/215552); basically, once you use `defer`, you've given up control on execution order.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) says: "_Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document._", though. I'd recall `defer` was buggy in some browsers when `defer` was introduced, for years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await` doesn't block the execution of the entire script. `await`s are just hiding promise(s) into a synchronous-looking construction. When `await` is met in a function marked as `async`, the expression following `await`, often a function call, is executed, but the return value is not waited inside the `async` function. Instead, the function marked with `async` is paused, and the execution continues from the point the `async` function was called, and the rest of the script is executed (and perhaps also other scripts), until the promise is fullfilled, Then the script execution resumes to the `async` function, and continues from the next statement after the statement where `await` operator originally paused the `async` function.

You can use a promise like this:

In script1:

```
const headerHtml = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("./header.html")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
         document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = data;
         resolve();
    });
});
```

In script2:

```
headerHtml.then(() => {
    // Now header.html is fully loaded
    // Do what you need to do with the new elements
});
```

This will work even when `fetch` would had been completely resolved before `then` handler is set in script2 (or anywhere in general), because "*If the promise has already been fullfilled or rejected when a corresponding handler is attached, the handler will be called*"<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Description)</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two as follows:

```
(async function() {
  await fetch("./header.html")
    .then(response => { return response.text() })
    .then(data => {
       document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = data;
       document.getElementById("some element in header.html").style.display = block
});
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go is to add the code in script2 to script1, basically having one script tag.
For Example :

```
(async function() {
  await fetch("./header.html")
    .then(response => { return response.text() })
    .then(data => { document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = data})
    .then(headerData => {code for script two})
})()
```