# async script loading with dependencies

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

let's assume we have this stack of script loaded as

```
<script async src="script1.js"></script>
<script async src="script2.js"></script>
<script async src="script3.js"></script>
<script async src="script4.js"></script>
```

async is making the page load much faster, and everyone is happy about it in case if all 3 scripts are independent of each other.

What about situation where script 4 needs script 3 to be able to load successfully, and
script 3 needs script 2.

How would you handle it without slowing down the page loading?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) instead of `async`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async and defer to load scripts in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978612/using-async-and-defer-to-load-scripts-in-order)