# Load RequireJS in head

Tags: javascript, requirejs, web-performance

My web site uses RequireJS for loading other scripts. Unfortunately the pages are compositions of independent little applications that are provided as HTML fragments (actually it's a Java portal) and a few of them contain inline scripts that depend on RequireJS modules.

The problem is that when RequireJS is loaded at the bottom, applications in the body cannot use it as it's not available yet.

So we came up with two solutions:

1. Move RequireJS to the `<head>` tag
2. Define a promise variable `requireJsLoadedPromise` in the first `<script>` of the  `head` that will be resolved after RequireJS is loaded. As it's the first script, every application can register a handler that will be called as soon as RequireJS is available. Scripts could use it like this:

```js
requireJsLoadedPromise.then(requirejs => requirejs(['my/module'], /* ... */);
```

As you can see solution 2 is more complex and is a non standard solution that will only work for applications that are specifically designed for it. It also causes more nesting due to the additional promise handler. Additionally it causes a script in the `<head>` like solution 1 as well, so maybe is equally bad as solution 1 in terms of page load performance.

I wonder what the drawbacks of solution 1 are. If loading RequireJS in the head will have a noticeable impact on the page loading performance that could justify solution 2.
But I rather assume that RequireJS will do little while loading and will perform its main work as soon as scripts start to call `requirejs()`. However I'm not sure about that.

Could moving to the `<head>` cause a noticeable impact?

Is there a even another better solution for this problem?

Comment: Why do you expect any drawbacks? It's very common to put scripts into the head and bundlers like Webpack put the scripts into the head.

Comment: It's a common best practice to put scripts at the bottom. In the head, scripts interrupt html processing

Comment: That "common best practice" is maybe 10 years outdated. Just add the attributes `async` and `defer`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: As an example you could inspect the code of Stack Overflow. Most scripts are placed in the head with attribute `async`.

Comment: Quick research shows that this is not possible: async won't guarantee script order anymore. So it could happen that RequireJS is loaded after the dependend script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53274388/395879

Comment: But `defer` guarantees the order: _"Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document."_ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) You can see it in the standard https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async

Comment: After reading the standard I think you want `defer` without `async`: _"If the script's type is "classic", and the element has a src attribute, and the element has a defer attribute, and the element is "parser-inserted", and the element does not have an async attribute 

    Add the element to the end of the list of scripts that will execute when the document has finished parsing associated with the Document of the parser that created the element.

    When the script is ready, set the element's "ready to be parser-executed" flag. The parser will handle executing the script.
"_

Comment: Putting scripts into the head with `defer` and without `async` is equivalent to putting all scripts at the end of the body.

Comment: Unfortunately some say you cannot trust `defer` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10731231/395879) and it won't work with inline scripts (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: RequireJS is relatively small and can also be loaded from a CDN. I would go with the simple solution of putting it in the head unless you can demonstrate that it causes an unacceptable delay in building the page which I doubt it will because it would be cashed in the browser if loaded via CDN and even if not it's small

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem in the project.

We implement the similar mechanism as Google DataLayer. In the head of the page we did a little script which had same API as RequireJS, but it just queued the scripts until the real RequireJS loaded. After load, it popped each item and called the real RequireJS.

If you have more questions feel free to ask.