# Will setting defer on my polyfill and other scripts guarantee that they're loaded in order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, polyfills

I'm using polyfill.io to polyfill Promise and fetch for older clients. On [their website](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/examples) they recommend using a script loader or their callback to make sure the script has loaded completely before running the modern code:

> We recommend the use of the async and defer attributes on 
>   tags that load from the polyfill service, but loading from us in a
>   non-blocking way means you can't know for certain whether your own
>   code will execute before or after the polyfills are done loading.
>
> To make sure the polyfills are present before you try to run your own
>   code, you can attach an onload handler to the https://cdn.polyfill.io
>   script tag, use a more sophisticated script loader or simply use our
>   callback argument to evaluate a global callback when the polyfills are
>   loaded:

However, shouldn't setting `defer` on both scripts already guarantee that they are loaded async but still in the order in which they appear in the document (unless the browser doesn't support defer)?

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="modernscript.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) `defer` attribute just defines a point of page loading time when script loading will occur.

From documentation that you've citated it can be seen:

> To make sure the polyfills are present before you try to run your own
> code, **you can attach an onload handler** to the https://cdn.polyfill.io
> script tag

Since (as pointed into comments to this answer) it can't be clearly seen if `defer` scripts will be executed ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413657/2633956), [2](https://www.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/)) and taking in mind possible browser implementation differences - it may be not the best idea to rely on such behavior.

So better way would be either:

1. to use some script loader ([RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/) for example)
2. to add proposed `onload` handler to first `<script>` tag and create dynamic `<script>` tag for loading your code inside this handler
3. to bundle your code together with Promise polyfill (manually or using bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)) and load as single bundle.

**UPDATE:** As pointed by @PeterHerdenborg in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011676/will-setting-defer-on-my-polyfill-and-other-scripts-guarantee-that-theyre-loade/47012106?noredirect=1#comment116317039_47012106) - MDN document now clearly states that:

> Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.

Comment: Well if you look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413657/5918874, people seem to believe that defer guarantees execution order. Also here: https://www.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/. I referred to the polyfill.io docs exactly because they state the opposite (but they're also talking about defer combined with async, which is different). And the mozilla docs don't say anything about it. Which is weird.

Comment: I see that it is probably my mistake: normal scripts loading process is blocking operation, `async` scripts are loaded asynchronously, `defer` scripts seems to define different point in time when they will start to load. polyfill.io docs suggests to add both `async` and `defer` attributes, that's why they suggest to add `onload` handler. I will remove my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Decided to update answer to include information from comments. Since there is no clear behavior definition in specs - it may be better idea to avoid relying on such type of loading and consider other alternatives instead.

Comment: Hmm yeah. Maybe we should ask for clarification in the mdn docs. Don't know if that's possible somewhere?

Comment: It can be done through [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/), there is `Other` -> `Mozilla Developer Network` product into bugs searching / filling forms

Comment: The MDN docs linked in this answer now state `Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.`

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg thank you, I've updated answer