# JS error only in Opera - Cannot convert x to object

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, opera

This error *only* occurs in the Opera browser. I've seen a few posts with a similar error, but i don't think the suggested solutions apply to my example. Most solutions say *x* is undefined. I don't think that applies, since i defer my script.

My html file:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="media.match.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="bgimg.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

`media.match.min.js` is a polyfill for `window.matchMedia()` for old browsers.

`bgimg.js` is my own script which updates the background image according to media queries.

I'll just post the entire first part of `bgimg.js` since it's in such an early phase (media queries omitted):

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");

// declare all media queries
var mqXS = window.matchMedia("...");
var mqS = window.matchMedia("...");
var mqM = window.matchMedia("...");
var mqL = window.matchMedia("...");
var mqXL = window.matchMedia("...");
var mqXXL = window.matchMedia("...");
var mqXXXL = window.matchMedia("...");

// create matching arrays to iterate
var queryLists = [mqXS, mqS, mqM, mqL, mqXL, mqXXL, mqXXXL];
var fileNames = ["_xs", "_s", "_m", "_l", "_xl", "_xxl", "_xxxl"];

// function to check media queries and load matching image
var checkQueries = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < queryLists.length; i++) {
        if (queryLists[i].matches) {
            var fileName = "url(images/ls/01" + fileNames[i] + ".jpg)";

            container.style.backgroundImage = fileName;
            break;
        } else {
            console.log("no match");
        }
    }
};

// run once
checkQueries();
```

So this works in all modern browsers, but throws this error in Opera:

`Unhandled Error: Cannot convert 'container' to object`

on line 27:

`container.style.backgroundImage = fileName;`

So maybe Opera has a bug up its butt about how i created `fileName`? Or is something else wrong with my script? Again, no errors are thrown in any other browser.

Comment: nope, nothing to do with fileName, Error says that container is not an object. Perhaps opera converts it to a string. Different browsers behave differently, thats why it is recommended to use jQuery for DOM manipulations - it gives you cross browser compatibility

Comment: This question might have benefited from [this Opera tag split request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276860/tag-split-or-add-request-opera-presto-vs-opera-blink). If @Bergi's answer helped you to solve your issue, please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to both [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982619/1048572), (pre-Blink) Opera does not support the `defer` attribute. However, [there seems to be a polyfill](https://gist.github.com/fearphage/881274) available.

Comment: i was just thinking if this might be the problem! thanks, i'll try it out.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you'll need to use any of the techniques presented in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572)

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm focusing on speed here, I just used the dirty method of moving my bgimg.js script to the end of the page and it's loading properly now.