# Access to .js file

Tags: javascript

We have an internal application that uses google map api to create a map tooltip. When the access to the google's mapping js file is blocked rest of the javascript on the site breaks too. Is there a way to prevent loading a js file if it's not accessable?

Comment: why is the google map js blocked?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141263/how-to-prevent-javascript-html-blocking

Answer (score 0):

First, i'd recommand using require.js to a smarter way of loading js scripts.

But if you don't want to go into that, maybe add "async" attribute to your script tag will do the trick.

Comment: If it works you should mark the question as solved so others will know that this is a good solution !